# rapid J2E application development with weblogic fast swap

Tags: java, war, rad, hotswap

I've been in the J2E apps for 15 years now but I've always found the WAR dev cycle very slow.
How do you make your code changes from IDE to app server immmediate ?

Today some  application servers or servlet containers are able to do so , based on exploded war deployment and by classes hotswap but what is the IDE support for exploded war incremental build ?

I wasn't able to find a free solution ( without $jrebel ) to rebuild incrementally ( understand only what has changed ) an exploded war. Based on a a maven project description or not.

In details : the exploded war must be updated with touched java source files -> updated classes and changed resources.
Our application server can handle the rest from that.

I'm pretty sure we are very close to the solution, but what ide / environement can enable this ?